# Array slide show not working smoothly with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Written some javascript (very new to this) to center the div and make it full screen adjusting as the window does, that works fine but now I have added some script I found online to transition from one image to another using an array. They seem to be contradicting each other messing up the animation, the biggest problem is when I resize the window. Here is my jsfiddle so you can see for yourself. Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/xPZ3W/

```
function getWidth() {
var w = window.innerWidth;
x = document.getElementById("wrapper");
x.style.transition = "0s linear 0s";
x.style.width= w +"px"; 
}

function moveHorizontal() {
var w = window.innerWidth;
x = document.getElementById("wss");
x.style.transition = "0s linear 0s";
x.style.left= w / 2 -720 +"px" ;         
}

function moveVertical() {
var h = window.innerHeight;
x = document.getElementById("wss");
x.style.transition = "0s linear 0s";
x.style.top= h / 2 -450 +"px" ;         
}

var i = 0; 
var wss_array = ['http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/8515/t/14/assets/slideshow_3.jpg?          48482','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0259/8515/t/14/assets/slideshow_5.jpg?48482'];   
 var wss_elem;

function wssNext(){

  i++;                                 
  wss_elem.style.opacity = 0; 

if(i > (wss_array.length - 1)){           
i = 0;                           
 }
 setTimeout('wssSlide()',1000);
}


function wssSlide(){
 wss_elem = document.getElementById("wss")
 wss_elem.innerHTML = '<img src="'+wss_array[i]+'">';       
 wss.style.transition = "0.5s linear 0s";

 wss_elem.style.opacity = 1;

setTimeout('wssNext()',3000); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have issues by using pure CSS to accomplish the resizing, or is this some sort of polyfill?

Comment: Cant seem to get it to work with pure CSS thought this was far more simple? Especially the centring the image on resize

Comment: Javascript may be more customizable and easier to do, but depending on the amount of content you're trying to fix it's way slower than accomplishing the same in CSS. You can have Javascript change up classes as you need to, but the transitions in CSS will always be smoother.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understand what you're trying to accomplish. You want a div to be centered on a page, and scale with the size of the window? Percent widths were made for that (you can even setup max-width and max-height to help with that.

Comment: So I can use CSS to transition between more than one image? The issue isn't the smoothness as soon as I resize it seems to crash. I also want the center of the image to be centered in the div

Comment: I noticed that too, the JS tries to do too much at once.

Answer (score 0):

So I whipped up this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c93aT/)** from scratch, and I hope it helps out. Pure CSS transitions from class to class using your array URLs to switch among the pictures.

Basically this just advances the "active" class to the next one everytime it's called, provided the first picture is set to "active" class.

```
var pics = document.getElementById('slideshow').children,
    active = 0;

function slideshow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        if (i == active && pics[i].className == "active") {
            console.log(i, active, (active + 1) % pics.length);
            active = (active + 1) % pics.length;
        }
        pics[i].className = "";
    }
    pics[active].className = "active";
    setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);
}
setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);
```

And here's the CSS, which absolutely positions the container, and hides all its children unless it has the active class, to which it will transition smoothly.

```
#slideshow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
}
#slideshow img {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
#slideshow .active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```